# Is there an alternative to NavigableSet when a "Set" is not appropriate?

Tags: java, list, data-structures, collections, set

The [`NavigableSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) interface offers a number of useful methods that a normal [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) does not (specifically I'm thinking about methods like `headSet` and `tailSet` for instance).  However, being a `Set`, it does not support duplicate elements.  Also, being a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html), the ordering must be consistent with `equals` and `hashCode` to avoid violating the contract of the `Set` interface.

Is there any good alternative data structure for when there might be duplicate elements or multiple elements that are "equal" according to the natural ordering or Comparator but not "equal" according to the `equals` method?  As a motivating example, consider the following code that shows why a `NavigableSet` is not appropriate:

```
public class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>{
  double x;
  double y;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Foo o) {
    return Double.compare(x, o.x);  // only x matters for sort order
  }

  public static void main(String...args){
    Foo a = new Foo();
    a.x = 1;
    a.y = 2;

    Foo b = new Foo();
    b.x = 1;
    b.y = 42;

    Foo c = new Foo();
    c.x = 2;
    c.y = 12.34;

    NavigableSet<Foo> set = new TreeSet<Foo>();
    set.add(a);
    set.add(a);
    set.add(b);
    set.add(c);

    System.out.println(set.size());
  }
}
```

Notice that element `a` only gets added once (of course, since this is a `Set`).  Also, notice that `b` does not get added, since there is already an element for which the comparison returns 0.

I felt like this was probably a fairly common thing, so I hoped to find an existing implementation rather than rolling my own.  Is there a good, widely-used data structure for my purposes?

I'll add that while writing this question I did come across the [Biscotti Project](http://code.google.com/p/biscotti/), but a) I'm not convinced it solves the comparison/equals issue and b) the FAQ explicitly says it's not really safe to use.

Comment: A List?  I feel like I missed something in your question.  Is it just that you want the automatic re-sorting when you add?  You don't have to roll your own entire collection to wrap a list in a utility method that sorts it after you add.

Comment: Yeah that would accomplish part of what I want, but then there are other utility methods that I mentioned like `headSet` etc.  I could implement all of those as well, or I could try to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan Is it a problem if you sort by x then by y (i.e. sort by y only if x is the same)? That would solve your issue...

Comment: @assylias I think it's a problem for things like `headSet` because it would be easy to miss elements in the head set that have the same x but different y.

Answer (score 0):

Let me reformulate your question to make sure I understand it well.
The need for `headSet` and `tailSet` implies the collection has to be sorted. Which is kind of in conflict with the need for allowing the duplicate members according to `compareTo`.

The conflict comes from the effective usage of such collection. Adding a member to sorted collection is done utilizing the `compareTo` method in *O(log n)* - kind of binary search and then add. The `TreeSet` is implemented using `TreeMap` which can't two same members according to `compareTo`.

What you are looking for won't be effective.

- You may try to use a simple `ArrayList` and sort it by `Collections.sort` and then use `sublist` method. The problem with this is that it don't deal with duplicates at all.
- You may also use the `LinkedHashSet` which deals with duplicates (according to `equals()` and it is *immune* to `compareTo()`), but it is not sorted. Of course, you may convert the `LinkedHashSet` instance to the `SortedSet` by passing its instance in constructor.

Comment: `LinkedHashSet` does not allow duplicates.

Comment: Thats what I ment, it doesn't allow two same entries according to equals() but the two entries could be "same" according to compareTo() (entry1.compareTo(entry2) == 0). What is important for LinkedHashSet, and what I forgot to add, is it that preserves the ordering.